# plotting the date and time on separate row in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, tidyverse, axis

How to format the x-axis label such that the hours are centred below the dates (not in line with the dates)?

```
library(lubridate)
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)

DF<- data.frame(Datetime = seq(ymd_hms("2011-01-01 00:00:00"), to= ymd_hms("2011-01-10 00:00:00"), by = "hour"),
                Var1 = runif(217, 5,10))
ggplot(DF, aes(x = Datetime, y = Var1))+
  geom_line()+
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = breaks_pretty(10), labels = date_format("%Y-%m-%d %H"))
```

Comment: `labels = date_format("%Y-%m-%d\n%H")`?

Comment: Thanks@Nate -  that was quick.

Comment: happy ggplot-ing!

Comment: @Nate That should be a solution.  Please post it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest modify the theme for axis labels with this:

```
library(lubridate)
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)

DF<- data.frame(Datetime = seq(ymd_hms("2011-01-01 00:00:00"), to= ymd_hms("2011-01-10 00:00:00"), by = "hour"),
                Var1 = runif(217, 5,10))
ggplot(DF, aes(x = Datetime, y = Var1))+
  geom_line()+
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = breaks_pretty(10), labels = date_format("%Y-%m-%d %H"))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=-90))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Good suggestion, I am stingy saving some spaces here. The angle would eat more space.

Comment: @Hydro It depends on how long your labels are. With that angle you will have aligned as you want! You can try other values. I hope that helped you!